# PHP autoloader: ignoring non-existing include

Tags: php, error-handling, autoload

I have a problem with my autoloader:

```
public function loadClass($className) {
    $file = str_replace(array('_', '\\'), '/', $className) . '.php';
    include_once $file;
}
```

As you can see, it's quite simple. I just deduce the filename of the class and try to include it. I have a problem though; I get an exception when trying to load a non-existing class (because I have an error handler which throws exceptions). This is inconvenient, because it's also fired when you use class_exists() on a non-existing class. You don't want an exception there, just a "false" returned.

I fixed this earlier by putting an @ before the include (supressing all errors). The big drawback with this, though, is that any parser/compiler errors (that are fatal) in this include won't show up (not even in the logs), resulting in a hard to find bug.

What would be the best way to solve both problems at once? The easiest way would be to include something like this in the autoloader (pseudocode):

```
foreach (path in the include_path) {
    if (is_readable(the path + the class name)) readable = true;
}
if (!readable) return;
```

But I worry about the performance there. Would it hurt a lot?

---

(Solved) Made it like this:

```
public function loadClass($className) {

    $file = str_replace(array('_', '\\'), '/', $className) . '.php';    
    $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        if (is_readable($path . '/' . $file)) {
                        include_once $file;
                        return;
                    }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only get called once per class, so performance shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function loadClass($className) {
     $file = str_replace(array('_', '\\'), '/', $className) . '.php';
     if(is_readable($file))
       include_once $file;
 }
```

is_readable won't make a huge performance difference.

Comment: Except that I'll have to do it for every include path (which there are about 4 on average, i'd guess).

Answer (score 0):

class_exists() has a second parameter `autoload` which, when set to FALSE, won't trigger the autoloader for a nonexistant class.

Comment: I know and if I set that to false the whole function is pretty useless to me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Solved) Made it like this:

```
public function loadClass($className) {

    $file = str_replace(array('_', '\\'), '/', $className) . '.php';    
    $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());
    foreach ($paths as $path) {
        if (is_readable($path . '/' . $file)) {
                        include_once $file;
                        return;
                    }
    }

}
```